# Check if Visitor show logon button

Tags: templating

I am trying to figure out how to check if a visitor is not logged in so that I can show the correct button. E.g

```
{% if craft.session.isLoggedIn %}
    <a href="{{ logoutUrl }}">Logout</a>
{% else %}
    {% craft.session.isGuest %}
    <a href="{{ logoutUrl }}">Client/a>
{% endif %}
```

What is the best method to display a "sign in" button for a visitor that takes them to a login page and then once logged in, show "Logout"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you'll want something like this...

```
{% if currentUser %}
    <a href="{{ url('logout') }}">Logout</a>
{% else %}
    <a href="{{ url('login') }}">Login</a>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thank Lindsey D, your method work perfect ! Much Appreciated